# Chain function call only works if you don't save a reference to an intermediate type

Tags: c++, read-access

I'm using function calls like this to set up an instrument:

```
Setup().Thing().Channel(1,2).Channel(3,4).At("foo");
```

I'd like to be able to write a setup function which takes a list of pairs of channels, and applies them in a for-loop: `for (...) setup.Channel(m,n)`. But if I assign the return value of `Thing()` or `Channel()` (the latter returns `*this` by reference), I get a runtime error: `Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this-> was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC7.`

```
auto& setup = Setup().Thing();
setup.Channel(1,2) // crashes here
     .Channel(3,4).At("foo");

auto& setup = Setup().Thing().Channel(1,2).Channel(3,4);
setup.At("foo"); // crashes here
```

The `this` in question, a.k.a. `setup`, comes from here:

```
function::SetupComponentFunction<SetupResult>& Thing(int index, std::string alias)
{
    auto type = std::make_shared<type::SetupType<T>>();
    auto function = std::make_shared<function::SetupComponentFunction<T>>(index, alias);

    setType(type);
    type->setFunction(function);

    return *(function.get());
};
```

Here are some of its members:

```
SetupComponentFunction<T>& Channel(int cha, int chb)
{
    memberFunction1(); // crashes when trying to step in here
    ...
    return *this;
}
std::shared_ptr<T> At(const std::string& alias)
{
    memberFunction2(alias); // able to step in here
    ...
}

// in base class:
#ifndef __INTELLISENSE__
    std::shared_ptr<attribute::AttributeItem> memberFunction1() override;
    std::shared_ptr<T> memberFunction2(const std::string& alias)
    {
        return memberVar(alias).get(); // crashes when trying to step in here
    }
#endif
boost::signals2::signal<std::shared_ptr<T>(const std::string&)> memberVar;
```

`memberFunction1()` and `memberVar` have no definitions that are visible to me. When you don't save `auto& setup`, they work fine but you can't 'step into' while debugging (it just steps over). When you do save `auto& setup`, you get the runtime error.

Is there anything here that suggests what the problem is? And is there a workaround? (A "chained function call builder"?!)

Comment: It looks like at least one of your functions returns by-value. If so, you cannot store a reference, it would be a reference to a temporary and it will become dangling at the end of the full-expression.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI `Setup()` is a constructor. `At()` returns a shared pointer. All functions in between return by reference.

Comment: Same problem with a constructor. You construct a temporary. Your reference will dangle. Say `Setup setup;` and your problem is fixed: you will be able to save as many intermediate references as you like.

Comment: `return *(function.get());` returns a referene to an  object that gets destroyed when the function returns. It is unclear why you use `make_shared` but then let the shared pointer be destroyed at the end of the function and at the same time return a reference. This is like `int& foo() { int a; return a; }` just made more complex

Comment: actually it depends. On `type->setFunction(function);` and other details you left out from the code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You must store a reference to head of the chain `Setup` ,assuming it doesn't return a refrence to its rvalue parameters (it doesn't have any here).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It works! Still a bit mysterious to me - I can do `auto& setup = Setup().Thing(); setup.At();` with the following code: `struct SetupResult {};
struct SetupFunc { SetupResult& At() { return SetupResult(); } };
struct Setup { SetupFunc& Thing() { return SetupFunc(); } };`

Comment: This example exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. Practically speaking, `setup` is a dangling reference; `setup.At()` doesn't crash and burn only because `At()` doesn't actually use `this` pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can't seem to provoke an error. E.g. printing `typeid(this).name()` in `At()` works. Also keep in mind that `memberFunction2()` didn't cause error.

Comment: Since `this` is not a pointer to a polymorphic type, `typeid(this)` is a compile-time constant - it doesn't require actually accessing memory pointed to by `this`. Anyway, undefined behavior is undefined. If it doesn't crash and burn immediately, that's actually the worst - chances are it'll break something later and in a seemingly unrelated part of program, and be a bear to debug.

Comment: `memberFunction2()` did cause an error at the point where it first attempt to use `this`, which apparently happened inside `memberVar`